# Hypothesis test

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

I have random samples $X_1, X_2, X_3$ from $bernoulli(p)$. The critical region for testing $H_0 : p \leq 1/2$ vs $H_0 : p > 1/2$ is $C =\{(x_1,x_2,x_3): \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \geq 2\}$.

Now I want to find the size of this test and the power function of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^3 X_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(3,p)$. Evaluate the probability of rejection with different values of $p$.